# sharepoint customize navigation bar

Tags: sharepoint

hi does any of oNE knoWs sharepoint put javascript in top of navigation bar near read line.
please see attach image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1sBu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Any JS can be globally placed with the SPFX Application Customizer.